# Error 1064 on Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_billing_details`()
BEGIN

 DECLARE offsetcount INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE totalcount INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

 set totalcount = (select count(*) from new.billing);


 loopall: LOOP


 BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE c_subsid varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE c_duedate varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE c_descriptions varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE c_debitamt varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
 DECLARE c_transdate varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 DECLARE c_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT subsid, descriptions, debitamt, transdate FROM new.billing limit 200 offset offsetcount;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN c_cursor;

 loopbilling: LOOP

 FETCH c_cursor INTO c_subsid, c_descriptions, c_debitamt, c_transdate;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE loopbilling;
 END IF;


insert into sakura.customer_bill_items (type ,name, description, amount, created_at) values (if(c_descriptions = "balance", 4, if(c_descriptions = "subscription", 1 , if(( c_descriptions like "%modem%" or c_descriptions like "%amplifier%" or c_descriptions like "%power supply%"), 2 , 3))) ,c_descriptions, c_descriptions, c_debitamt, c_transdate);

insert into sakura.customer_monthly_bill_items (customer_id, bill_item_id, start_billing_date) values ((select a.id from sakura.customer a where a.subscriber_id = c_subsid), last_insert_id(), c_transdate); 

insert into sakura.customer_billing_details (bill_item_id, subscription_plan_id, bill_item_amount) values (last_insert_id(), (select subscription_plan_id from sakura.customer_subscriptions where customer_id = (select id from sakura.customer where subscriber_id = (select subsid from new.subscriber where subsid = c_subsid))), c_debitamt);

insert into sakura.customer_billing_header (customer_id) select a.id from sakura.customer a where a.subscriber_id = c_subsid;

update sakura.customer_billing_details set header_id = last_insert_id() where id = last_insert_id();

 END LOOP loopbilling;

 CLOSE c_cursor;

END;


 set offsetcount = offsetcount + 200;

IF offsetcount >= totalcount THEN 
 LEAVE loopall;
 END IF;


 end LOOP loopall;

END
```

and it works properly on my machine but when I try to run it on a server, it returns with:

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'offsetcount;    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET
>   v_finished = 1;    OP' at line 31

I'm using Workbench 5.5.54 and our server is running 5.1.66. I have been searching for an answer for hours now but i have no luck. Hope somebody helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this:

```
offset @offsetcount;
```

this is the cause of your error

try to add this:

```
OPEN c_cursor;
     @offsetcount = @offsetcount + 1;
 loopbilling: LOOP
```

then use query in where clause "`where subid > @offsetcount`"

I think you need to use [while loop](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html) just for checking the table if has a record or done all record are done.

Comment: I really need that offset because i'm running too many records which causes a timeout so i need to do it by batch.

Comment: offset with variable doesn't work instead of change it to a real number like 10 or any number not a variable.

Comment: but i need it to increment so that it loops across all my data. My PC could run it but our server can't. My PC not that high end so I need our server to do the work.

Comment: how? could you please help me. I am new to this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the subsid is varchar.